# Notification number and Rep change boxes suddenly stopped disappearing after reading

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've read all my inbox items and reviewed my rep changes by tapping on the top-right red box and green box. They disappeared after closing the popup menu.

However, after a page refresh, they both came back with exactly the same value on them. It seems I just can't dismiss them.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. Reproduced on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 59.0.2

Comment: It also occurs if you open a new (different) SE link (on the same or another site).

Comment: I was literally just about to post the same thing. Windows 7, Opera.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about this. We touched the caching code on Friday the 13th like a bunch of morons and to no one's surprise, it broke.

But we fixed it.

Comment: Well I suppose it was Friday 13th, which is traditionally the most unlucky of days, so not surprising you goofed ;) Thanks for fixing it ...